# how to select phpmyadmin sql query box using selenium and send value to it?

Tags: selenium

i am trying to select phpmyadmin SQL query textarean using selenium but it's not working, as any query you add it will be converted to spans in a div not an actual textarea, please advise.
i tired this using xpath but not working

queryBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "xpath=//div[@id='sqlquerycontainerfull']/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div/pre")

[screenshot for my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEMoD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the xpath for phpMyAdmin(version 4.0.10.18) query box

```
"xpath=//*[@id="sqlquerycontainerfull"]/div/div[1]/textarea"
```

To send values to textarea,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="sqlquerycontainerfull"]/div/div[1]/textarea")).sendKeys(("myData");
```